# allow user to add/delete buttons and buttons automatically shifts positions

Tags: android, android-layout

i would like to create a flexible user interface for the android platform.

basically my layout would consist of a image button with at "plus" sign at the beginning.
when teh user clicked it. another layout is called where the user is prompt to name the image button that is suppose to be created.When the user clicks confirm, he'll e brought back to the 1st layout and the newly added image button would replace the position of the "plus" sign image button and the plus sign image button would shift to the right.

i know how to create the layout initially but i dunno how to programmed it to function the way i described above.

ok so now i have my main layout file set this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout 

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"  >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addRoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:src="@drawable/plus" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="@+id/addRoom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addRoom"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/addRoom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addRoom"
        android:text="@string/add_room"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

would i have any issues when i include the fragments to shift the image button and textview when the alignment instructions to both of it.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to manipulate your activity's UI in real time by the user it's recommended to use Fragments and Fragment Manager to change diffident parts of your activity's view.

You can find great information in the docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

or

http://marakana.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial

in your case you would do some thing like that:

```
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.remove(plusButtonFragment)
.add(R.id.containerForFragments,userNewFragment)
.add(R.id.containerForFragments, plusButtonFragment)).commit();
```

after you have created the **plusButtonFragment** and the **userNewFragment**.

**Update:**

For managing the fragments location in a relative layout check out the next post:

[How to add fragments programmatically in relativelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196682/how-to-add-fragments-programmatically-in-relativelayout)

Comment: i understand your above sample code is to call and replace the image button but is there a way to setup the placing too? i plan to make it 2 image button each row.my xml layout is relative layout.